# IE Conditional Statement to disable a specific script (IE8 only)

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, if-statement

I'm a complete newbie/rookie in web design, but I have come across an issue for one of my sites that I'm currently designing. I saw that 2 similar questions were posted on stackoverflow (one being spot on), but I wasn't able to discern the answer...probably because I'm not very advanced.

I want to know...is there a way to disable a specific script within an IE8-only conditional statement?

Let me explain: I have a rounded corner script that works absolutely beautifully in Firefox, Safari, and IE9. However in IE8, if the background of the parent div is an image (which they all are in this case), the rounded corners fail to appear transparent and instead show as annoying little white fill. (My site is http://gkplusjm.com)

I was able to find some great CSS code that I could implement for IE8, and I have successfully done so in a ie8.css file through a IE conditional statement. I know it works because when I removed the corner script completely and viewed the page with the ie8.css, it was acceptable enough for my liking. However, I put the script back in so it would function on all other browsers, and the problem reared its head again. So what I really need is to find a way to disable that script, but only if the viewer is using IE8. Seems simple enough, but I can't find the fix. Some of the codes I have tried include:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="scripts/jquery.corner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

and also this:

```
<!--[if !(IE 8)]><!-->
<script src="scripts/jquery.corner.js"></script>
<script>
    // your inline script goes here
</script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Option #2 seemed to have worked for the other person who posted this question, but I couldn't figure out what to put in the part that reads "your inline script goes here" to make this disable work.

Any advice is appreciated.

Many thanks,

gk

Comment: Just so you know, rounded corners can be done in pure CSS (`border-radius`) in all browsers other than IE8 and earlier. So you really dont need (and shouldn't be using) a rounded corner script in Firefox, Safari or IE9. For IE6/7/8, the best rounded corner script is [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/). This hacks IE to make it work with the standard CSS rounded corners.

Answer (score 3):

ahhhh! i was able to figure it out from another person's stackoverflow question. i wanted to post the solution here in case any other newbie (like myself) ran into the same issue.

so the problem was that i was interpreting the IE conditional statement incorrectly. i thought that the one i was using meant, "if the visitor is using IE8, disable this script...". as such, i had the script i wanted to disable in IE8 in that conditional statement, but i was also leaving it in the regular HTML code for the other browsers to pick-up & use.

after doing more research on the IE statement i was using, i realized it was a downlevel-revealed conditional comment, meaning: "For something to appear in ‘other browsers’ except for IE8". once i understood this, i DELETED the script from the regular HTML code and ONLY placed it within this conditional comment below:

```
<!--[if !IE 8]><!-->
    <script src="scripts/jquery.corner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Why do you use the extra <!--> tags? See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html for the correct syntax. In any case, conditional comments are phased out and no longer supported in IE10: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: His command works correctly. The 'not' commands work in everything except what he chose. If 'not' ie8 works in non-ie browsers as well as ie 10+ because that is what they were designed for. So if 'not' ie8 does in fact do what it says. There is an if 'NOT' ie command [ ! IE ] that is similar.